# Installed Qt 4.7.4 on the Mac but can't find the IDE editor: qtcreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have installed Qt5.1 on the Mac and it was easy to find the IDE editor: qtcreator.  Infact you could click on a project pro file and it would come up.  I removed Qt5.1 and installed Qt4.7.4.  But I can't find the editor qtcreator?  I can find qmake, example applications that were built... But I can't even click on a project pro file to get qtcreator to come up.

Comment: Is it possible you just installed the Qt Libraries, without Qt Creator?  Try downloading the IDE separately: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed using the Qt binary installer you should have a folder in `/Users/(your-username)/Qt`, ordinarily the `Qt Creator.app` exists in there. OS X is potentially linking the `.pro` file extension to a version of Qt Creator that no longer exists, so it's not set with the version installed as the main handler.

Other ways to find Qt Creator:

- Try searching for it in Spotlight if you have it setup to index your drive
- Search from Terminal with something like `sudo find / | grep "Qt Creator.app"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /Users/<USERNAME>/Qt<VERSION>/Qt\ Creator.app /Users/mac/Applications/Qt\ Creator.app
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: sorry about that a was searching for solution and when i realized it . i remembered this Q. sooo i sent it like this because it's obvious.